# Cast text from json to Date

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, casting

I have this json field and i want the result as a date.

```
select t.config_exit::json ->> 'earliest_exit' as Earliest_Exit
from table t
```

This give me `null` or for example `2021-11-03` as result but as a text field.

```
select t.config_exit::json ->> 'earliest_exit'::date as Earliest_Exit
    from table t
```

Ive tried this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the json expression between parenthesis, e.g.

```
SELECT (t.config_exit ->> 'earliest_exit')::date
FROM t;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=54c13c5597645b0e2e356dd7cca91588)

```
WITH t (config_exit) AS (
  VALUES ('{"earliest_exit":"2021-11-03"}'::jsonb)
)
SELECT (t.config_exit ->> 'earliest_exit')::date
FROM t;

    date    
------------
 2021-11-03
```

It will fail in case `earliest_exit` is empty, so you might want to filter them out before casting. Alternatively you can use `to_date`, but it would maybe give you dates you don't want:

```
WITH t (config_exit) AS (
  VALUES ('{"earliest_exit":"2021-11-03"}'::jsonb),
         ('{"earliest_exit":""}'::jsonb),
         ('{"earliest_exit":null}'::jsonb)
)

SELECT to_date(t.config_exit ->> 'earliest_exit','YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM t;

    to_date    
---------------
 2021-11-03
 0001-01-01 BC
 
(3 Zeilen)
```